# Woocommerce receipt hook don't work correct

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm developing payment gateway for Woo and try to use `woocommerce_receipt_` hook for submit custom form and redirect customer to third part web payment service. Any one with idea why hook doesn't work. Thanks for helping!! Cheers!

This is my payment class code:

```
class my_vpos extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
  function __construct() {

      // The global ID for this Payment method
      $this->id = "my_vpos";


      $this->method_title = __( "my_vpos", 'my_vpos' );


      $ this->method_description = __( "Payment Gateway Plug-in for 
        WooCommerce", 'my_vpos' );
      $this->title = __( "my_vpos", 'my_vpos' );


      $this->has_fields = false;

      // This basically defines your settings which are then loaded with 
         init_settings()
     $this->init_form_fields();

     $this->title = $this->get_option( 'title' );
     $this->init_settings();


     $this->testurl = 'https://www.exaple-payment.com/pay-gw-t/vpos';
     $this->liveurl = 'https://www.exaple-payment.com/pay-gw-t/vpos';

     // Actions


     add_action( 'woocommerce_receipt_' . $this->id, array( $this, 
     'receipt_page'));
 } // End __construct()


    function receipt_page( $order ){
      echo '<form action="' . $this->testurl . '" method="post" 
      id="submit_payment_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="PAYLOGIN"/>
            </form>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code in function.php file

```
<?php
    add_action('plugins_loaded', 'woocommerce_my_vpos_init', 0);
    function woocommerce_my_vpos_init(){
      if(!class_exists('WC_Payment_Gateway')) return;

      class WC_My_Vpos extends WC_Payment_Gateway{
        public function __construct(){
          $this -> id = 'my_vpos';
          $this -> medthod_title = 'My Vpos';
          $this -> has_fields = false;

          $this -> init_form_fields();
          $this -> init_settings();

          $this -> title = "My Vpos";
          $this -> description = "Payment Gateway Plug-in for  WooCommerce";

          $this -> testurl = 'https://www.exaple-payment.com/pay-gw-t/vpos';
          $this -> liveurl = 'https://www.exaple-payment.com/pay-gw-t/vpos';

            add_action('woocommerce_receipt_my_vpos', array(&$this, 'receipt_page'));
          }




        /**
         * Receipt Page
         **/
        function receipt_page($order){
            echo '<form action="' . $this->testurl . '" method="post" 
              id="submit_payment_form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="PAYLOGIN"/>
                    </form>';
        }

        }
       /**
         * Add the Gateway to WooCommerce
         **/
        function woocommerce_add_my_vpos_gateway($methods) {
            $methods[] = 'WC_My_Vpos';
            return $methods;
        }

        add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'woocommerce_add_my_vpos_gateway' );
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I have plugin structure, but `woocommerce_receipt_my_vpos` not work. Thaks for helping.

Comment: try this code 
add_action('woocommerce_receipt_my_vpos', array(&$this, 'receipt_page'), 10, 1);

Comment: No success, after I click `place order` button site give error `Internal Server Error`

Comment: ok. reference woocommerce receipt

http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_receipt_id/